# Angular Directive - NgModelCtrl Parser Issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

I have a directive to show a symbol depending on the value of a field. This is attached to a field as follows:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="" class="text-input" ng-class="example_class" ng-model="exmaple-model" my-directive />
```

And a directive as follows:

```
module.directive("myDirective", function () {
    return {
        require: "?ngModel",

        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            /*breakpoints show the line above and below are reached*/
            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (val) {
                /* call to function to show symbol, this line is never reached */
            }
```

The code is reaching the `ngModelCtrl` line, but reaches no further. Debugging has shown that while the `ngModelCtrl` looks to be built correctly (has functions and values, etc.) the `$parsers` is empty - the length is 0, the functions that should be there aren't.

Looking at the Chrome inspector yields no errors. Are there any reasons for the `$parsers` to be blank, or is there a way to debug the directive any further?

Comment: Why you have two link methods? (or just bad copied?) I guess ngModel should **not** be optional (without ?)

Answer (score 2):

Your parser is showing 0 length, try to return some value from the parse method and use it as follows:

```
function parse(value) {
  if (value) {
    return value.toLowerCase();
  }
}
ngModelController.$parsers.push(parse);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://alexperry.io/angularjs/2014/12/10/parsers-and-formatters-angular.html

Have you tried putting your logic directly where you have "call to function to show symbol" vs calling the function?